# Extraer elementos de un dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con el dataframe adjuntado en la imagen. Me piden extraer **el máximo valor del número de nacimientos por país.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se extraer la edad del paciente cuyo value es el máximo:

```
attach(Down_syndrome)
age_maxvalue<-EDAD[VALUE==max(VALUE)]
```

Este código me daría el resultado para todo el data frame completo pero como indico arriba me piden que lo filtre por países.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más básica es usar `aggregate()` para agrupar por país, el tema es que debes trabajar sobre el `data.frame` y no sobre las columnas individuales, tal como lo estás haciendo luego del `attach`. La idea sería algo así:

```
aggregate(EDAD ~ COUNTRY_REGION, Down_syndrome, max)
```

La notación de fórmula: `EDAD ~ COUNTRY_REGION` indica que vamos a agrupar por `COUNTRY_REGION` y aplicar una función sobre `EDAD`, en este caso `max`

Answer (score 0):

Usando la librería dplyr puedes hacer lo siguiente:
Primero ordenar tus datos agrupandolos por `COUNTRY_REGION`

```
df <- Down_syndrome %>%
      group_by(COUNTRY_REGION) %>%  
      summarise(nacimientos = sum(VALUE))
```

Luego para poder ordenar de mayor a menor

```
df_orden <- df[order(-df$nacimientos),]
head(df_orden)
```